# drupal 6 forms type = select multiple = true... what is the returned value?

Tags: drupal-6

There doesn't seem to be any details about this in the forms api. So please forgive my question, but I need to know what is being returned when i submit values from a form field where I can select multiple values. I suspect it is an array, if so, how is it structured? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  To improve your question (and likelihood of getting an answer), you could include some code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a dump of the value field from the  $form_state variable after submission for a form that contains 2 multiple select lists. *Countries and Currencies. As you can see, you are correct, an array of values corresponding to the selected option values is returned for each of the 2 lists:

> ```
> [values] => Array
>     (
>         [name] => PayPal
>         [ppid] => 17
>         [countries] => Array
>             (
>                 [236] => 236
>                 [237] => 237
>             )
> ```

```
        [currencies] => Array
            (
                [USD] => USD
                [EUR] => EUR
                [CAD] => CAD
            )

        [submit] => Submit Details
        [form_build_id] => form-d675700e434f656b0e1c7ac4aa91a210
        [form_token] => 3405b88547c068a0f6a2742670b2149a
        [form_id] => add_payment_method_form
        [op] => Submit Details
    )
```